# li with runat server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a problem with creating dynamic <li> elements from codebehind. I need to assign runat server to li, but I didnt find a way to assign runat server, so I can't find that li control when I need to change the attributes from code behind. Is there any answer to my problem? I am new to asp.net c#.

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" runat="server" id="tabList">
     //First i got ul control that i assign runat=server in aspx page
</ul>

//then i create li from code behind in Page_Init()
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl tab = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("li");
tab.ID = "tab" + (i + 1);
tab.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");//this is not working
tab.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a href=\"#customer" + (i + 1) + "\" data-toggle=\"tab\">Penumpang " + (i + 1) + "</a>"));

//then i add the li to my ul controler called tablist
this.tabList.Controls.Add(tab);
```

My problem is, when the page loads, I can see the li on the page, but I cannot call li from the code behind when i need to do something with it. Is there any way to call the li in code behind? Or change the li attributes when it is assigned dynamically? Sorry for bad English.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `Attributes` collection is for HTML attributes. `runat="server"` is not an HTML attribute.

Comment: instead of using html li, if that ok to use asp control like listview or repeater to generate?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578824/how-to-generate-unordered-list-dynamically-in-asp-net

Comment: actually i only need controlling html li or accessing it, because i create li dynamically for creating how much tab needed, then i got dropdownlist event if it selected, the selected tab which is the li control will be active(the attributes will be changed), and i dont know how to use listview or repeater to doing the li job @Se0ng11

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot access the `<li>` in your code-behind is because it is dynamically generated.

Dynamically generated controls lose their state when they are rendered on the view and for you to access them again in your code-behind when a postback occurs, you need to recreate them before playing with them. So basically, you need to recreate them everytime on your postback to access their properties and values and to manipulate with them.

Also, `runat='server'` wont work from code-behind. Instead of using `<li>`, you could also try using some ASP.NET controls such as `Listview` or other data-binding controls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: only li control that i didnt get, i create the textbox dynamically and i can access it, as i said in comment above i just need access the li to change the attributes, thanks for the advice @HarveySpecter