# How to use a menu item as a header in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sitecore

I am using a modification of the navigation menu here (Demo #2)

http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index2.html

The website is tied to Sitecore so there are FieldRenderer's and Literals throughout the site.

As you can see when a user opens the menu and clicks on a link, the menu shifts over and the title is pushed to the top. My issue is that all of this is hardcoded into the menu itself. Is there a way that when a user clicks on one of the menu items, in the h2 tag, is there a C# method or Javascript function I can use so that instead of it being hardcoded into the menu, the title appears in the h2 tag? I basically followed the navigation menu that is written, only instead of there being a hardcoded, li tags, I use ListViews.

```
 <ul class="main-menu">
   <li class="something">
    <div class="mp-level">
       <h2 class="icon icon-world">Item  1</h2>
       <a class="mp-back" href="#">Back</a>
          <ul class="test">
          <asp:ListView ID="Copys" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="CopysTemplate"
 OnItemDataBound="Copys_ItemDataBound">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="CopysTemplate" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li class="header-item" runat="server" id="CopysItem">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HeadsLink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink></li>
             </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:ListView>
          </ul>
   </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: doesn't `listView` already create a `<ul>`? If so your markup is invalid

Comment: the listview is pulling from Sitecore, the ul tag is used for css values

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Both your <ul> tags are nested with other tags. You can only have <li> listed within <ul>. Include your <ul class="test"> as part of ListView's layout template. Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578824/how-to-generate-unordered-list-dynamically-in-asp-net

Comment: i just copied the code in wrong, there is a li tag there

Comment: u can use by datalist also <ul><asp:DataList ID="dltest" runat="server" Width="100%" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow"> <ItemStyle Width="25%" HorizontalAlign="Center" /><ItemTemplate> <li style="width: 100%">   //linkbutton </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
                        </ul>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but generally Sitecore.Context.Item can be called to get the current page you are on. If you are trying to pull the current page's title into the menu, that's probably your best bet. Once you have the item, you can render out whatever field you have for the title.

Answer (score 0):

> Not completely sure about the question, but from what I gather, you want to inject the title from a sitecore datasource item to the text ofyour h2 DOM element. One of
>   the most important bits of information you left out is what type of
>   item you're getting your data from. But I'll try to help you out anyway.
>
> Layout Level:

```
//Code behind of layout file        
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item scTitle = Sitecore.Context.Item;

<!--Front End of layout file -->
    <h2 class="icon icon-world"><%=scTitle.Fields["TitleFieldName"] != null ? scTitle.Fields["TitleFieldName"].Value : "Some Fallback Value"%></h2>
```

> Sublayout Level:

```
//Code behind of sublayout file
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item scTitle = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(((Sublayout)Parent).DataSource);

<!--Front End of sublayout file -->
        <h2 class="icon icon-world"><%=scTitle.Fields["TitleFieldName"] != null ? scTitle.Fields["TitleFieldName"].Value : "Some Fallback Value"%></h2>
```

> There are some tools like GlassMapper that makes referencing your
>   datasources and their fields a bit cleaner. But this would work.